# The degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is at most $2$ because $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}] = 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field

> [image]

Before you answer, yes i am aware of the outcome of the solution by a "brute force" method of finding the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. I just want to know what the authors (Dummit/Foote pg 526) are talking about in their reasoning.

In the first sentence they claimed, the degree extension is $\leq 2$ because $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Comment: Dummit and Foote *said*, "The degree of the extension . . .  ***is at most $2$***"; ***you*** said it is less than $2$!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis no that's what I mean they are saying $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] < 2$, I don't get how it follows from just $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}] = 2$. If anything it should be *at least* $2$.

Comment: Where exactly do they say $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3): \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)] < 2$?  I'm not seeing it . . .

Comment: They are saying $\leq2$, not $<2$

Comment: Since $\sqrt{3}$ is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}/,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is **at most $2$**.

Comment: $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3): \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)] < 2$ iff $x^2 - 3$ is reducible over $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2): \Bbb Q]$.

Comment: @Arthur I still don't see how it is $\leq 2$ even if relax the inequality

Comment: @RobertLewis, they say  $= 2 \iff x^2 - 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. If we negate this, it doesn't immediately imply $<2$ (what about $>$?)?

Comment: It would imply "$< 2$" if $x^2 -3$ were reducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, which it's not; that's what they proved in the remainder of the paragraph.

Comment: But from their phrasing, they are saying it is at most $2$ from just $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}),\mathbb{Q}] = 2$, the rest are just future considerations.

Answer (score 1):

We have $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt3):\Bbb Q]=2$. This means that there is an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ with rational coefficients where $\sqrt3$ is a root. (One such polynomial is $x^2-3$, although the exact polynomial expression is of little importance..)

Now for $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt2):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]$. It corresponds to the degree of an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ where $\sqrt3$ is a root. Clearly the polynomial from before is a polynomial with valid coefficients and the right root. Is it irreducible? Don't know, don't care. Regardless, there is an irreducible. polynomial of either first or second degree with $\sqrt3$ as a root, meaning the extension has either degree $1$ or degree $2$.

Comment: So what you saying is that $x^2 - 3$ would just be a candidate in "polynomial with valid coefficient and the right root"? Because if you knew priori this is the right polynomial, there is no choosing of degree 1 or 2? What if there is for example, say a polynomial with the right requirements but of degree 3?

Comment: @Hawk Then it would necessarily be reducible. The fact that we have a candidate polynomial means the degree of the true polynomial can't be _higher_ than that.

Comment: I see. That is a good point.